# Drools condition not working with eval()

Tags: spreadsheet, drools, rule-engine, rule

I am using Drools with spreadsheets and I want the user to be able to add complex code in the condition cells. But for some reason this isn't working.

Here's an example:

[image: Example]

The code in the condition cell is valid, but I get the following exception from the Drools compiler:

```
[17,0]: [ERR 102] Line 17:0 mismatched input ''
[11,330]: [ERR 101] Line 11:330 no viable alternative at input 'partnumber' in rule "CAS_12"
```

I hope you guys can help me.. Thanks!

---

**[Update]**

I found the solution for my problem: after setting the EscapeQuotes property to false, the text in the condition-cells is forwarded as it is to the eval function. This way I can programm using DRL inside the cells.

This is how to set the property:

[image]

Comment: How do you get partnumber from you fact? Can you show a bit more of your decision table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution:

All I had to do, was to add EscapeQuotes=false to the decision tables properties. This way, the " aren't escaped by Drools and the text entered in the condition cell will be used as it is.

Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: I managed to ran into to exact same error message, although my condition is different. Where did you exactly add the property?

Comment: And what I found by my searches was that you can get this error also if your locale uses quotation marks(non-ascii) not supported by Drools. Some have managed to get past this problem by escaping the strings themself, i.e. `partnumber str[startswith]\"ABC\"`. Didn't work for me though.

Comment: I updated my first post with the solution and an image which shows where to set the property. It's in the spreadsheet header of the Drools descision table.